# Extracting tags from a XML file

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have a XML file like this:

```
<root>
    <class id="CRWebService" url="http://webservice.click-rent.es/">
        <metodos>
            <metodo id="login">
                <descripcion>
                    <![CDATA[Envia la validación mediante la cabecera del documento SOAP para acceder a cualquier método de la clase.]]>
                </descripcion>     
            <parametros>
                <parametro>
                    <nombre>Login</nombre>
                    <tipo>Object</tipo>
                    <contenido>
                    <variable>
                        <nombre>user</nombre>
                        <tipo>String</tipo>
                        <descripcion>
                            <![CDATA[Nombre de usuario.]]>
                        </descripcion>
                    </variable>
                    <variable>
                        <nombre>password</nombre>
                        <tipo>String</tipo>
                        <descripcion>
                            <![CDATA[Contraseña.]]>
                        </descripcion>
                    </variable>
                </contenido>
                <descripcion>
                    <![CDATA[Nombre de usuario y contraseña suministrados por Click&Rent. Para validar estos parámetros es necesario enviarlos mediante una cabecera SOAPHeader.]]>
                </descripcion>
            </parametro>
        </parametros>
```

As you can see I have some "descripcion" fields which I want to extract and write them in a file. I'm making a parser with PHP but I'm sure that there would be a piece of software which could do this, or a regex which could help me save a few hours of code. That would be my first question: is there any tool or quick trick to extract the content of all the tags which match with a keyword ("descripcion" in this case)?

If there's no way, I'd like to do the most generic tool but with SimpleXML I've seen that I have to know the node names and such. Do you know how to read the full XML tree without knowing the names of the nodes in PHP?

Thank you all fellas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex; use a parser.

SimpleXML has [children()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) which lets you go through the children without knowing the name. You can use it recursively to make a list of all description nodes.

Pseudo code:

```
function handleChildren($node, $search_key)
{
  for($node->children() as $child) {
    if ($child->getName() == $search_key) {
       //Write to file
    }
    handleChildren($child, $search_key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath to fetch data from your XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// iterate over any descripcion element in the document
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//descripcion') as $description) {
  $text = $description->nodeValue;
  // write to file
}
```

You can think of Xpath for an xml document like you think of SQL for a database. It is a specific language for expressions that describe parts of an data source.

It has native support in the most DOM implementations (PHP, Javascript in all major browsers, ...)

Comment: What does exactly Xpath do? can you explain more your answer, please?